# Android custom seekbar's progress not aligned with background

Tags: android

I am creating a custom SeekBar using 9 patch images.
The problem here is that on the first launch, the progress section is not aligned with the background.

Here's what it looks like on first launch:

[image]

And here's what it should look like, and actually looks like on later launches of the application:

[image]

The first behavior only appears after compilation or the application is killed in the app manager.

Here's the code for the progress bar:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:id="@android:id/background"
              android:drawable="@drawable/bar_whole"/>

        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <clip android:drawable="@drawable/bar_selected" />
        </item>

</layer-list>
```

One thing that might be of interest as well, I set the thumb and progress drawables when constructing the object:

```
protected void init()
    {
        this.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.volume_progress));
        this.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.volume_thumb));
    }
```

Thanks.